# A problem about the limit of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Problem: If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(R,\mathscr{B}(R))$, then define $\mathscr{A}$ to be the collection of all $A\in\mathscr{B}(R)$ such that the following limit exists and is finite:$(D\mu)(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu(A\cap[-n,n])}{n}$.
My question is:
1. is $\mathscr{A}$ an algebra?
2. If $R\in \mathscr{A}$, is $\mathscr{A}$ an algebra?
3. Is $D\mu$ countably additive on $(R,\mathscr{A})$?
I just do not how to start it.
$\mathscr{B}(R)$ means the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $R$.

Comment: No, $\mathscr{A}$ is not stable by finite intersection hence is not even an algebra.

Comment: That $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $B\in\mathscr{A}$ does not imply that $A\cap B\in\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: Try $A$ the set of even numbers and $B$ the set of even numbers in some $[4^n,2\cdot4^n)$ and of odd numbers in some $[2\cdot4^n,4^{n+1})$, for every $n$. Then $A$ and $B$ both have density $\frac12$ but $A\cap B$ has no density.

Comment: Rather, $A\cap B$ is made of all the even numbers in the intervals $[4^n,2\cdot4^n)$ for every $n$, hence the limit $(D\mu)(A\cap B)$ does not exist since the ratios $\frac1k\#(A\cap B\cap[0,k])$ oscillate between roughly $\frac16$ and roughly $\frac13$.

Comment: I already prove that $(D\mu)(A)=\frac{1}{2}$. But I find $(D\mu)(B)$ and $(D\mu)(A\cap B)$ is challenging for me, especially to give explicit formula of $\#(A\cap B\cap [0,k])$ and $\#(B\cap [0,k])$

Comment: Why are you deleting your comments once I answered them?

Comment: I am sorry I am new here, I do not know the rule. I just I want to make the content neat for other users to read.

Comment: Deleting your comments makes mine difficult to follow hence, if indeed what you want is "to make the content neat for other users to read", your action is counterproductive.

Comment: How about comment it again as before to make up?

Comment: How about following the rules of the site? (And if ever you have the time, someday, perhaps, reacting to answers and/or comments to your other questions).

Comment: @Did. Hello! I am still thinking the hint you provided. I am also will to follow the rules. Could you please be more specific about the rules. And also if you can make you comment as answer. It would be an excellent one.

Comment: Rules: why not you doing your job and finding them yourself on the site?

Comment: @Did．I tried my best and showed my effort to prove this problem. What you think is obvious in your comment is not really obvious. Please see my answer.

Comment: Where did I use the word "obvious"? Enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think $\mathcal{A}$ is necessarily a sigma-algebra, especially when $\mu$ is not finite, just sigma-finite. Here's an example. Take the counting measure on the positive integers. Then sets such as $P$, the set of primes has $(D\mu)(A)=0$, since by the prime number theorem there are roughly $n/\log n$ primes less than $n$. On the other hand consider the set $C$, the set of integers which do not have a $1$ as their first digit, e.g. $9,981$, are ok but $10$ is not. This set doesn't have a limit, as you can easily show (it does have a limsup). Since $C$ is the countable union of singletons, all of which are in $\mathcal{A}$, and limit 0, this means $\mathcal{A}$ is not a sigma algebra.

Comment: How about the countable additivity?

Comment: @user81235: sorry, could you clarify your question? In my example the contradiction implies the lack of countable additivity

Comment: Notice that whenever $n$ has a 1 infront, the size of $C\cap[-n,n]$ stays constant. This is not insignificant. For example if $n=1000$ then you have to wait till $n=2000$ to gain another element. In other words when $n=10^k$, you have to wait till $2n$ to gain another element. But this halves the total density. So it goes up and down to $1/2$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @user81235: $C$ is a set for which you have no measure. We can write $C$ as a countable union of singletons all of which have measure 0. So IF your measure was countable additive then we have a contradiction since the measure of $C$ must be zero.

Comment: Could you please write down more details about $(D\mu)(C)$ does not have limit? It seems obvious, but it is hard for me to write it formally.

Comment: @MikeBrown Try to find an upper bound of the density at integers $10^n-1$ (just before the beginning of an interval of integers whose first digit is $1$) and a lower bound of the density at integers such as $2\cdot10^n-1$ (at the end of an interval of integers whose first digit is $1$). If the limit of the former is strictly less than the limit of the latter (it is), you are done.

Comment: This is very helpful hint. In my opinion, the answer does not solve whether it is an algebra.

Comment: @MikeBrown: what is still unclear? The fact that it's not an algebra has been explained in the last few sentences of the answer.

Comment: You only proved the countable union does not belong to $\mathscr{A}$: take the union of countable singletons, and prove the union does not belong to $\mathscr{A}$. But the problem wants that, finite union does not belong to $\mathscr{A}$. If one is not a sigma algebra, we cannot tell it is not an algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathscr{A}$ is not even an algebra. Here is the counterexample.
Let $A$ denote the set of even numbers and $B$ the set of even numbers in some $[4^n,2\cdot 4^n)$ and of odd numbers in some $[2\cdot 4^n,4^{n+1})$, for every $n$. Then, $A$ and $B$ both have density $\frac{1}{2}$
but the limit of $\frac{1}{k}\#(A\cap B\cap [0,k])$ does not exist. I will prove $(D\mu)(A)=\frac{1}{2}$. One has $(D\mu)(A)=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mu(A\cap [-n,n])}{n}$. One has $\#(A\cap [-k,k])=\#(A\cap [0,k])=\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor+1$. Then, one has $(D\mu)(A)=lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor+1}{k}=\frac{1}{2}$. **BUT I have difficulty to prove $(D\mu)(B)=\frac{1}{2}$ AND $(D\mu)(A\cap B)$ OSCILLATE BETWEEN ROUGHLY $\frac{1}{6}$ AND ROUGHLY $\frac{1}{3}$ since I cannot provide the explicit formula like $(D\mu)(A)$.**

Comment: If you do not know whether this example works or not, why do you use this example?

Comment: @MikeBrown. It is provided by Did. It seems trivial to him (her). But it is not trivial to me.

Comment: @Did. Could you please provide more hint of proving $(D\mu)(B)=\frac{1}{2}$ and calculation of $(D\mu)(A\cap B)$?

Comment: Sorry but where did I say that the example I suggested in a comment was trivial? (Add some appreciation about (1) flooding the page with offtopic comments to justify that one is not following the rules of the site and (2) putting words in someone's mouth.)